# accessing elements of a list and it isnt callable?

Tags: python

Just for reference my code

```
def makeList (start,end,h):
    a=[]
    a.append(start)
    n=(end-start)/h

    while(n!=0):    
        new=a[-1] +h
        a.append(a[-1] +h)
        n=n-1
    return a

def generateBase(xList,f):

    if(len(xList)==0):
        return []
    elif(xList[0]==0 or len(xList)==1):
        return ([(xList[0],0,0)] + generateBase(xList[1:],f))

    else:
        return ([(xList[0],0,(f(xList[0])))] + generateBase(xList[1:],f))

def getThird(a):
    return a[2]

def fdm(alpha,startx,endx,startt,endt,dx,dt,f):
    baseSolution=generateBase((makeList(startx,endx,dx)),f)
    totalSoltuion= baseSolution + startCalc(alpha,(makeList(startx,endx,dx)),(makeList(startt,endt,dt))[1:],baseSolution,dx,dt,[],[])

def startCalc(alpha,xList,tList,phiSolutions,dx,dt,newPhi,newX):
    print newPhi
    if(len(tList)==0):
        return []
    elif (len(xList)==1):
        return ([(xList[0],tList[0],0)] + startCalc(alpha,(newX + [xList[0]]),tList[1:],(newPhi + [(xList[0],tList[0],0) ]),dx,dt,[],[]))
    elif (xList[0]==0):
        return ([(xList[0],tList[0],0)] + startCalc(alpha,(xList[1:]),tList,phiSolutions,dx,dt,(newPhi + [(xList[0],tList[0],0)]),(newX + [xList[0]]))) 

    else:
        print getThird(phiSolutions[0])
        print getThird(phiSolutions[1])
        print getThird(phiSolutions[2])
        sol=newPhi(xList[0],tList[0],getThird(phiSolutions[0]),getThird(phiSolutions[1]),getThird(phiSolutions[2]),alpha)
        return ([sol] + startCalc(alpha,(xList[1:]),tList,phiSolutions[1:],dx,dt,(newPhi + [sol]),(newX + [xList[0]]))) 




def newPhi(x,t,phiL,phiC,phiR,dx,dt,alpha):
    return (x,t,(phiC + (alpha*(dt/(dx**2)))*(phiR-(2*phiC)+phiL)) )

def showMe(SolutionList):
    GraphSolution(SolutionList)

showMe(fdm(1,0,1,0,1,.1,.01,(lambda x:x+1)))
```

The issue is here

```
sol=newPhi(xList[0],tList[0],getThird(phiSolutions[0]),getThird(phiSolutions[1]),getThird(phiSolutions[2]),alpha)
```

I get this issue

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

The things in these arrays are real numbers, i thought this issue only happens when i try to call a list like a function if i did like phiSolution(0) im not sure thought whats the issue, i print everything out and its a number, if someone could give me some insight that would be great.

Comment: Please show the complete traceback.  Also, why are you defining a function `getThird` instead of just doing `phiSolutions[0][2]`, etc.?

Comment: @BrenBarn...esp since `getFirst` and `getSecondAndAllTheOnesAfterThat` are clearly just as important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your recursive call:

```
return ([(xList[0],tList[0],0)] + startCalc(alpha,(newX + [xList[0]]),tList[1:],(newPhi + [(xList[0],tList[0],0) ]),dx,dt,[],[]))
```

In particular, look carefully at your argument list. It breaks down to these arguments:

```
startCalc(alpha, # arg 1
          (newX + [xList[0]]), #arg 2
          tList[1:], #arg 3
          (newPhi + [(xList[0],tList[0],0) ]), # arg 4
          dx, # arg 5
          dt, # arg 6
          [], # arg 7
          []) # arg 8
```

According to your definition of `startCalc`...

```
startCalc(alpha,xList,tList,phiSolutions,dx,dt,newPhi,newX)
```

... `newPhi` is argument #7 by position. Therefore, when you make your tail-recursive call, an empty list is being assigned to `newPhi`. So `newPhi` *is* a list, and `sol=newPhi(<anything>)` is indeed attempting to call it. If you're trying to index into the list, use brackets:

```
sol = newPhi[index]
```

Also, as mentioned in another answer, you're using the identifier `newPhi` both as a function name and an input argument name to startCalc. You need to change one of these to resolve the conflict.

Comment: I see i named a parameter and function the same thing. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2):

Because `newPhi` is a list, and therefore is not callable.

Note that you have defined `newPhi` twice: Once as a function (at about line 48 in the code, between the definitions of `startCalc` and `showMe`), and once as the 7th parameter to the `startCalc` function at about line 29. The definition in force when the `TypeError` is raised is the one where it's a `startCalc` parameter.

`startCalc` is called by the second line of the `fdm` function at about line 27:

```
    totalSoltuion= baseSolution + startCalc(alpha,(makeList(startx,endx,dx)),(makeList(startt,endt,dt))[1:],baseSolution,dx,dt,[],[])
```

And if you'll count 7 parameters in, you'll see that you're passing an empty list (`[]`).

If you want `newPhi` to be a function there, move the definition *above* the definition of `startCalc`, and rename the current `newPhi` parameter which is interfering with your `newPhi` function. You cannot have it be both a list (see lines 34 and 36) and a function (line 42).